# Private/Public Key Authentication for Windows Remote desktop

Tags: remote-desktop, authentication, windows-server-2012-r2

Does anything exist for Windows RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) that is similar to SSH (in Linux) Public/Private key authentication (Instead of leaving normal password authentication open)?

I'm finding conflicting answers to this topic around the internet. I'm hoping to be able to just distribute a private key to client devices instead of using a complex password on every login (assuming I do not want to eventually disable password authentication totally).

Comment: By refusing to incorporate a connection protocol that specifically prevents password-guessing, the halfwits at Redmond require that the remote machine be strictly no more secure than a machine infested with their insecure bloatware. Why am I not surprised when MSFT fails on the datasec front?

Answer (score 7):

Remote Desktop supports X.509 client certificates, under the "smart-card authentication" name. Despite the name, it *should* work with locally-installed certs/keys (i.e. without an actual smart-card). Though it does however require an Active Directory domain, as far as I know.

So, sort of but not really in a way that's useful to you.

Comment: Would you like to expand it a little... Is it without RDP Gateway?

Answer (score 1):

Without an AD domain, a possibility to prevent simple username & password access would be:

1. Installing OpenSSH for Windows (from https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases or on Windows 10 & 2019 it's an available feature),
2. Using an SSH client to log on with keys,
3. Disabling password authentication over SSH (uncomment and set "password authentication" to "no" in %ProgramData%\ssh\sshd_config),
4. If you need the graphical interface, configure your SSH client to tunnel RDP over SSH (https://www.saotn.org/tunnel-rdp-through-ssh/),
5. Disabling "regular" RDP traffic (TCP port 3389) over the network (not on local Windows Firewall!) so that password logon can't be used.

There might be better options for a few $$$. I've heard of Yubico's solution for example (with hardware token): https://support.yubico.com/support/solutions/articles/15000028729-yubico-login-for-windows-configuration-guide

Comment: That Yubico page 1. refers to a TWO factor solution that starts with a password. I believe the question is about NOT using a password. 2. Doesn't say anything about RDP.  Did you have a different Yubico product in mind?

Comment: This tunnelling solution seems to adds an ssh key requirement on top of the regular, password-based RDP authentication, correct? Interesting and more secure but I believe the question is about _replacing_ the inconvenience of a password with private key.

Comment: maybe auto login or no password on the rdp side